# Using pinvoke in c# to call sprintf and friends on 64-bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, pinvoke

I am having an interesting problem with using pinvoke in C# to call _snwprintf. It works for integer types, but not for floating point numbers.

This is on 64-bit Windows, it works fine on 32-bit.

My code is below, please keep in mind that this is a contrived example to show the behavior I am seeing.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _snwprintf([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder str, IntPtr length, String format, int p);

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _snwprintf([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder str, IntPtr length, String format, double p);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Double d = 1.0f;
        Int32 i = 1;
        Object o = (object)d;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(32);

        _snwprintf(str, (IntPtr)str.Capacity, "%10.1lf", (Double)o);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        o = (object)i;
        _snwprintf(str, (IntPtr)str.Capacity, "%10d", (Int32)o);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
   0.0
     1
```

It should print 1.0 on the first line and not 0.0, and so far I am stumped.

Comment: What kind of demon could drive you to pinvoke C runtime printf family? C calling convention, variable arguments, non-OS deployed dlls, its like breweing the perfect storm!

Comment: Isn't string.Format good enough for you?

Comment: @Remus - I realize that this is not a nice thing to do and is asking for trouble, however sometimes we all have to live with existing code. Besides, despite how horrible it may be, it still seems to me like it should work.

Comment: @zneak - I would love to use string.Format instead of this, but in this case I must use with printf-style format specifiers. If this can't work, the other solution I am considering is writing a function to convert from printf format strings to c# ones, and then use string.Format.

Comment: @bde: ah, I see then. Though parsing a printf-style format string to a C# format string might make it more portable than PInvoke.

Comment: @everyone, I agree with bde, here we should try to help him, with agreement that ofcourse he knows what he is doing, sometimes you cant spend thousands of dollors to rewrite entire application, but we need to be smart enough to save time to write patches in our software.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, even if it's not something many people would need. +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your calls do not work, but the [secured versions of these methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx) do work properly in both x86 and x64.

The following code does work, as expected:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _snwprintf_s([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder str, IntPtr bufferSize, IntPtr length, String format, int p);

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _snwprintf_s([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder str, IntPtr bufferSize, IntPtr length, String format, double p);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Preallocate this to a given length
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(100);
        double d = 1.4;
        int i = 7;
        float s = 1.1f;

        // No need for box/unbox
        _snwprintf_s(str, (IntPtr)100, (IntPtr)32, "%10.1lf", d);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        _snwprintf_s(str, (IntPtr)100, (IntPtr)32, "%10.1f", s);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        _snwprintf_s(str, (IntPtr)100, (IntPtr)32, "%10d", i);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The same problem happens if I use Single instead of Double. I'll change the example to use lf though. See the main comments for why I am trying to do this.

Comment: @bde: I just redid my answer.  The code posted there works in x86 and x64, with no issues.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with the undocumented __arglist keyword:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _snwprintf(StringBuilder str, int length, String format, __arglist);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Double d = 1.0f;
        Int32 i = 1;
        String s = "nobugz";
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(666);

        _snwprintf(str, str.Capacity, "%10.1lf %d %s", __arglist(d, i, s));
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Please don't use that.

Comment: Sorry for duplicated post, didn't see your __arglist when posted my answer :)

Comment: I actually had tried that earlier today, and I couldn't get it to work. All this sample code does for me is print the format string. Maybe I am missing something here. I agree that I'd rather not use this method though.

Comment: @bde: Project + Properties, Application tab, Platform Target = x86.  Such are the hazards.

Comment: that fixed it, but that's bizarre. So the secret __arglist thing isn't supported for x64?

Comment: @bde: my interpretation is that __arglist can't get the x64 calling convention right.  It is a tricky one since the first 4 arguments are passed in registers.

Answer (score 0):

uint is 32 bits.  The length parameter of snprintf is size_t, which is 64 bits in 64 bit processes.  Change the second parameter to IntPtr, which is the closest .NET equivalent of size_t.

In addition, you need to preallocate your StringBuilder.  Currently you have a buffer overrun.

Comment: Tried that, same problem. I'll update my example though, it should be using IntPtr anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try MarshalAs R8 (Thats for real/floating 8 (which is double)) on last parameter in second function.

Comment: I just read msdn help, the 2nd parameter expected is in form of parameter array, I am not aware of how to marshal this to c's parameter array, even if you are sending your parameter as double, may be runtime is not expecting it in the same form, i wonder how int worked and so does double should work too. try sending it as first item in array of double in last parameter and try puting params.

Comment: C and C++ varargs are very different underneath from .NET parameter arrays.  sprintf definitely uses pass-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2840231/Alternative-using-MSVCRT-sprintf.aspx (this is actually note to CodeProject article)

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx