# Is there a way to convert C-format strings for C# -format strings in C#/.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, c, string-formatting

So i would like to convert string like this:

```
"Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of booze and ate %d bananas"
```

with a C# equivalent for .Format or .AppendFormat methods

```
"Bloke {0} drank {1,5:f2} litres of booze and ate {2} bananas"
```

sorry but i'm not sure if the C# version was correct but u got the idea. The solution does not have to be perfect but cover the basic case.

Thanks & BR -Matti

answered in my other question [How to write C# regular expression pattern to match basic printf format-strings like "%5.2f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098533/how-to-write-c-regular-expression-pattern-to-match-basic-printf-format-strings-l)

Comment: How about a string search and replacement based solution?

Comment: anything that is quite fast! the majority of the strings do not have those C-placeholders so it should be fast when there is 0 C-placeholders. This is definitely not trivial and I wonder if solution already exists since this could be common problem.

Comment: Similar question by the OP that tied to this one: [How to write C# regular expression pattern to match basic printf format-strings like "%5.2f"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098533/)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use `StringBuilder.Replace()`.

```
StringBuilder cString = new StringBuilder("Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of booze and ate %d bananas");
cString.Replace("%s","{0}");
cString.Replace("%5.2f", "1,5:f2"); // I am unsure of this format specifier
cString.Replace("%d", "{2}");

string newString = String.Format(cString.ToString(), var1, var2, var3);
```

Conceivably you could add something like this to as an extension method to String, but I think your biggest problem is going to be the specially formatted specifiers. If it is non-trivial in this aspect, you may need to devise a regular expression to catch those and perform the replace meaningfully.

Comment: if it was this easy i wouldn't have asked: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: that was an example. hence "convert string _like_ this".

Comment: -1: This is a hard-coded solution to a problem which cannot be hardcoded.  A working solution would be much more complicated than this.

Comment: @matti - When I first read your question, it sounded a little simpler than what it seems now. Have you looked at this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479153/using-pinvoke-in-c-to-call-sprintf-and-friends-on-64-bit

Comment: @joel - thanks. so people have the same problem. i just don't want 2 call C printf.

Comment: @matti - Understandable, but it probably is easier than writing a new sprintf function according to the grammar. If you can limit the subset of specifiers you need to replace, you might be able to implement some sort of regex solution, but it's still going to be tricky.

Comment: I would think long and hard before doing p/invoke calls to read strings. You stated that the booze and banana code above is an example. Would your converter require knowing all possible formats from sprintf? Or is there a specific sub-set? This is a non-trivial problem but moving into re-using old C++ libraries is can be even more troublesome.

Comment: sorry but i din't see the latest comments. but the class to get these strings is made years ago. and it's a subset so quite basic solution would do. see my other question about the regex to find them.

Answer (score 1):

First attempt: this (kinda) ignores everything between a `%` and one of `diouxXeEfFgGaAcpsn` and replaces that with a `{k}` where `k` goes from 0 to a maximum of 99 (not checked in code: more than 100 `%` in the input returns a bad format string).

*This does not consider the `*` in a directive special.*

```
#include <string.h>

void convertCtoCSharpFormat(char *dst, const char *src) {
  int k1 = 0, k2 = 0;
  while (*src) {
    while (*src && (*src != '%')) *dst++ = *src++;
    if (*src == '%') {
      const char *percent;
      src++;
      if (*src == '%') { *dst++ = '%'; continue; }
      if (*src == 0) { /* error: unmatched % */; *dst = 0; return; }
      percent = src;
      /* ignore everything between the % and the conversion specifier */
      while (!strchr("diouxXeEfFgGaAcpsn", *src)) src++;

      /* replace with {k} */
      *dst++ = '{';
      if (k2) *dst++ = k2 + '0';
      *dst++ = k1++ + '0';
      if (k1 == 10) { k2++; k1 = 0; }
      /* *src has the conversion specifier if needed */
      /* percent points to the initial character of the conversion directive */
      if (*src == 'f') {
        *dst++ = ',';
        while (*percent != 'f') *dst++ = *percent++;
      }
      *dst++ = '}';
      src++;
    }
  }
  *dst = 0;
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char test[] = "Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of booze and ate %d bananas";
  char out[1000];

  convertCtoCSharpFormat(out, test);
  printf("C fprintf string: %s\nC# format string: %s\n", test, out);
  return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort. as it says in the title i'm looking for C#2.0 solution. I naturally understand C so I check if it makes sense to convert it to C#. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroposting but here is mine partial solution:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"%[+\-0-9]*\.*([0-9]*)([xXeEfFdDgG])");
//prepare for regex
string csharpformat = originaltext.Replace("%%", "%").Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}").Replace("%s", "{0}");
                
newFormat = pattern.Replace(csharpformat, m =>
{
    if (m.Groups.Count == 3)
    {
        return "{0:" + m.Groups[2].Value + m.Groups[1].Value + "}";

    }
    return "{0}";
});
```

It catches %.2f and converts to {0:f2}