# How to write C# regular expression pattern to match basic printf format-strings like "%5.2f"?

Tags: regex, c#-2.0

It should match the following criteria (conditional parts are in square brackets:

```
%[some numbers][.some numbers]d|f|s
```

notation d|f|s means that one of them has to be there.

Thanks & BR -Matti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string input = "Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of water and ate %d bananas";
string pattern = @"%(\d+(\.\d+)?)?(d|f|s)";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

I didn't use `[dfs]` in my pattern since I planned to update it to use named groups. This is based on [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4097456/) about figuring out a replacement strategy for C-style format strings.

Here's an idea:

```
string input = "Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of water and ate %d bananas";
string pattern = @"%(?<Number>\d+(\.\d+)?)?(?<Type>d|f|s)";

int count = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m =>
{
    var number = m.Groups["Number"].Value;
    var type = m.Groups["Type"].Value;
    // now you can have custom logic to check the type appropriately
    // check the types, format with the count for the current parameter
    return String.Concat("{", count++, "}");
});
```

---

C#/.NET 2.0 approach:

```
private int formatCount { get; set; }

void Main()
{
    string input = "Bloke %s drank %5.2f litres of water and ate %d bananas";
    Console.WriteLine(FormatCStyleStrings(input));  
}

private string FormatCStyleStrings(string input)
{
    formatCount = 0; // reset count
    string pattern = @"%(?<Number>\d+(\.\d+)?)?(?<Type>d|f|s)";
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, FormatReplacement);
    return result;
}

private string FormatReplacement(Match m)
{
    string number = m.Groups["Number"].Value;
    string type = m.Groups["Type"].Value;
    // custom logic here, format as needed
    return String.Concat("{", formatCount++, "}");
}
```

Comment: Matches on "%%d" even though it probably shouldn't (hard to tell from question though)

Comment: Using alternation for single characters when a bracketed character class would work is unnecessarily wasteful.

Comment: @tchrist: your character class is good, agreed. There's a reason I did it this way, still in the process of editing...

Comment: @user470379: hmm couldn't reproduce... used `%%d bananas`. Do you have an example?

Comment: thanks a lot. this is answer to my earlier question! i have to really dig into it since i'm not familiar with regex. also have to convert it to C#2.0 which is not a biggie ;)

Comment: @matti updated with a C#/.NET 2.0 approach. Perhaps you can link your other question here or flag it and request it be deleted.

Comment: what can i say... thanks again? really appreciate. i'll change it a bit and try it. then accept it!

Answer (score 2):

```
%(?:\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?[dfs]
```

Is the answer to your question, but I suspect you may have asked the wrong question, as `printf` admits rather more than that.

Comment: thanks a lot! i know but i got limited set of strings to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an expression matching all fields of format strings of printf/scanf functions.

```
(?<!%)(?:%%)*%([\-\+0\ \#])?(\d+|\*)?(\.\*|\.\d+)?([hLIw]|l{1,2}|I32|I64)?([cCdiouxXeEfgGaAnpsSZ])
```

It is based on [Format Fields Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx). According to this specification `%[flags][width][.precision][{h|l|ll|L|I|I32|I64|w}]type` match groups will contain: `#1 - flags, #2 - width, #3 - precision, #4 - size prefix, #5 - type.`

Taken from [here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3363).