# How can I use P/Invoke to call a 64-bit C++ DLL from a 64-bit C# Application?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, gdkpixbuf

I'm working on some code that involves using P/Invoke to call unmanaged functions from a few C++ DLLs.  I'd like to be able to build the application as either 32 or 64 bit.

Currently, it only works as x86.

I have 32 and 64 bit copies of each of the referenced C++ DLLs and am using the following code to change the DllDirectory depending on whether the app is built as x86 or x64 (/lib/x64 holds the 64-bit dlls, /lib/x86 holds the 32-bit ones):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

string libPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "lib", (Environment.Is64BitProcess == true ? "x64" : "x86"));
SetDllDirectory(libPath);
```

The rest of my unmanaged C++ functions are defined as follows:

```
[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void g_type_init();
[DllImport("libgobject-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void g_object_unref(IntPtr pixbuf);
[DllImport("librsvg-2-2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size(string file_name, int width, int height, out IntPtr error);
[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern bool gdk_pixbuf_save(IntPtr pixbuf, string filename, string type, out IntPtr error, __arglist);
```

The code that actually uses these functions looks similar to this:

```
g_type_init();
IntPtr ptrError;
IntPtr ptrPixbuf = rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size(filePath, width, height, out ptrError);
if (ptrError == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    bool isSaved = gdk_pixbuf_save(ptrPixbuf, outputPath, outputFormat, out ptrError, __arglist(null));  //this line fails when compiled as x64!
    if (isSaved && File.Exists(outputPath))
    {
        return outputPath;
    }
}
g_object_unref(ptrPixbuf);
```

As I mentioned, everything works fine when running the application as x86 on my local machine (Windows 7 x64).  However, when I compile it as an x64 application, I get an "AccessViolationException" at the call to gdk_pixbuf_save().

Any ideas?  I'm relatively new to interop code, but I think it might have something to do with how the IntPtr variables are sent to/from the unmanaged code?  But why is it different from x86 to x64?

Comment: You are going to have to debug it so you'll at least have an idea which argument is wrong.  Set a breakpoint on the native C++ code and take it from there.

Comment: __arglist is undocumented, so maybe it just doesn't work after all...

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the extra parameters instead of using __arglist?

Comment: Yup, I'm looking at the `__arglist` too. This cries out for C++/CLI.

Comment: I only used `___arglist` because that's what an example that I found had used.  That being said, I tried deleting it from the function call, and I get the same result:  it succeeds on 32-bit builds, and fails on 64-bit builds.  Also, I don't really have access to the native C++ code.  I mean, it's a Gnome library, so it's available, but I haven't looked in to debugging it in Windows at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to all who commented -- you sent me down the right path, and helped me solve an underlying problem.

Originally, I wanted to have an x64 build *just in case* it was necessary...and it ended up being just that.

As it turns out, [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479153/using-pinvoke-in-c-sharp-to-call-sprintf-and-friends-on-64-bit#comment2471191_2479429) are correct.  On x64 builds, the undocumented `___arglist` keyword does not function as intended.

I can't comment on what, specifically, goes wrong.  The comment I linked mentions the possibility of the calling convention not being set correctly.  I'm not sure how this works...doesn't x64 only have *one* calling convention, anyway?

**Whatever, back to the point:**

I changed my `DllImport` for `gdk_pixbuf_save` to look like this:

```
[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool gdk_pixbuf_save(UIntPtr pixbuf, string filename, string type, out UIntPtr error, UIntPtr arglist);
```

The key here is that I'm passing in the final parameter, `arglist`, as `IntPtr` instead of `___arglist`.

Actually, I'm passing it in as `UIntPtr` because I switched all of my original `IntPtr` objects to `UIntPtr`.

That being said, when I call the function, it looks like this:

```
bool isSaved = gdk_pixbuf_save(ptrPixbuf, outputFilePath, outputFileFormat, out ptrError, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

As my `___arglist` is empty (there are other, optional, parameters that could be specified), the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save) tells me it should be null terminated.  To accomplish this, I pass in `IntPtr.Zero` (or `UIntPtr.Zero`, in my case).

Now, my code compiles, runs and I (more importantly) have access to 64-bits' worth of memory.

Thanks again to those who commented on my post - without your pointers toward the `___arglist` parameter, I'd have been completely clueless.

Comment: Well done! Aside: rather than using SetDllDirectory you can call LoadLibrary with the full path to the DLL before calling any other pinvokes. Just another way to do it.