# DCMTK: wrapped dcmsend dll called from C# gives error when called more than once

Tags: c#, dllimport, dcmtk

I am attempting to integrate DCMTK 3.6.4 (a C++ library) into a C# environment. While I have successfully wrapped the DLL

To that end, I've taken the code for dcmsend, wrapped it in an 'extern "C" {}', put '_declspec(dllexport)' before the main method, and exported it to a DLL. I am then calling this DLL from C# using this code.

Here is the DLLImport:

```
[DllImport("dcmsend.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "main")]
public static extern int dcmsendMain(int argc, string[] argv);
```

I call the method like this; ip, port and filename are all strings, and all valid.

```
dcmsendMain(5, new string[] { "dcmsend", "-v", ip, port, filename });
```

When I call the above method only once, it outputs this text:

```
I: checking input files ...
I: starting association #1
I: initializing network ...
I: negotiating network association ...
I: Requesting Association
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)
I: sending SOP instances ...
W: DcmItem: Length of element (7fe0,0010) is not a multiple of 2 (VR=OW)
I: Sending C-STORE Request (MsgID 1, SC)
I: Received C-STORE Response (Success)
I: Releasing Association
I:
I: Status Summary
I: --------------
I: Number of associations   : 1
I: Number of pres. contexts : 1
I: Number of SOP instances  : 1
I: - sent to the peer       : 1
I:   * with status SUCCESS  : 1
```

However, all subsequent times that the method is called in the same session, even if the filenames are different, produce this output:

```
W: no data dictionary loaded, check environment variable: DCMDICTPATH
I: checking input files ...
I: starting association #1
I: initializing network ...
I: negotiating network association ...
I: Requesting Association
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)
I: sending SOP instances ...
W: DcmItem: Length of element (7fe0,0010) is not a multiple of 2 (VR=OW)
E: DcmSequenceOfItems: Parse error in sequence (7fe0,0010), found (fffe,e000) instead of sequence delimiter (fffe,e0dd)
E: cannot send SOP instance from file: IM-0001-0000.dcm: Sequence Delimitation Item missing
F: cannot send SOP instance: Sequence Delimitation Item missing
I: Aborting Association
```

As the output states, the subsequent operations are not properly sent either.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: A string in c language is terminated with '\0'  and an array of strings would have two zeroes at the end.  What is happening is the first time you make the call there are zeroes at the end while later then zeroes are not there.  To prove I'm right a quick fix would be to add two zeroes to the end of the filename : filename + "\0\0"  You are calling standard calling convention which is handled different from c language calls.  I haven't used standard calling in a very long time and would have to do more research.

Comment: @jdweng Gave the quick fix a try, and tried changing to a Cdecl too, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304864/marshaling-variable-arguments-arglist-or-alternative

Comment: Unfortunately @jdweng has a long track record of talking nonsense on this topic. The classic C main argc and argv is categorically not a double null terminated string. The argv argument is an array of C strings. You know when you reach the end because the argc argument tells you the length array. Perfectly likely the problem is not the marshaling, but in the DLL. To confirm this you should make a dummy DLL with the same entry point but have it simply print out the arguments that are passed. Prove that the marshaling is correct, and then look elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I ran a check as you specified and the correct arguments are passed, even in subsequent calls. I think the problem might be on DCMTK's end (so, the DLL). There's a lot of code in said DLL, so I'm hesitant to post it here, but it's open source, so I could link to the source code and point out which lines are changed.

Comment: At this point this question isn't going to be useful because the issue is in the code we can't see.

Comment: And David has even a long track record of making comments about other people responses and NEVER giving a solution.  These aren't my answers, there other people answers.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not talking about your links. I'm talking about the mistake you keep making in believing that `char* argv[]` is a double null terminated character array. It is not. It is an array of null terminated character arrays.

Comment: I was hoping that everything was continuous in memory just to prove my theory.  It didn't work so it everything is not continuous.

Comment: @jdweng On a previous occasion I demonstrated the difference between array of pointer to null terminated character array and pointer to double null terminated character array. But you didn't want to accept that then. You seem to be accepting it now. I hope you remember for next time!

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the fact that the DICOM data dictionary could not be loaded by dcmsend (see warning message in log output).