# Convert a float to char[] without memory allocation

Tags: c#, memory, allocation

Do you know how to convert a float into a buffer of chars, without allocating any memory?

=> I simply want to re-do the same thing as float.ToString() do ; so I can put the result into a buffer instead of allocating a string

I wrote a function, but it doesn't handle very well the "rounding":

- 39.71 becomes "39.709996"
- 39.71001 becomes "39.710004"

That's because 39.71 as a float is a rounding of the stored value in memory which is 39.709996. With some rounding in my function I can easily come to something like this:

- 39.71 becomes "39.71"
- 39.71001 becomes "39.71"

Which is not great either, as I would like to keep the exact same algorithm of `float.ToString()` that manages to write "39.71" and "39.71001"

Do you know how this `float.ToString()` works exactly ?

Precision on my objective : I want to append a great lot of float (mixed with other types) in a very large string - and allocate this string only one time at the end to avoid too much garbage collection. So I really need to convert the float into an array of char (whatever the exact type format, just no unmutable string)

Comment: its not possible to store something without allocating any memory.

Comment: You need to have some allocation, as you need to allocate at least the string you'll be returning from the function

Comment: I don't mean to get a function already made, but to understand how the float.Tostring() algorithm work, and make a custom function from it

Comment: @Gaddy floating point is tricky. If you *really* want to do it yourself, you would need to do an unsafe pointer-based change to an `uint` (or `ulong` for `double`), and inspect the individual bits using bit operations, by understanding how IEEE floating point numbers are specified. It is not trivial.

Comment: additional: checking the coreclr code, the current version isn't exposed as c# - it is an `InternalCall`, provided directly by the runtime: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Number.cs#L305-L306

Comment: @Marc Gravell : yes absolutely, it's not trivial and i'm not sure to be able to do it. That's why I come here to see if I can get some advices/hints on the general algorithm to use

Comment: @Marc Gravell: thanks ; i don't know much about uncompiling C# source code, that means we can't access this source code at all ?

Comment: Question: why do you specifically need `char[]`? Would `char*` or `Span<char>` suffice? If so, you can get them from a `string`, so probably using the regular `ToString()` is your best bet

Comment: This seems like an X-Y question. *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to append a lot lot of float (mixed with other types) in a very large string - and allocate this string only one time at the end. So I really need to convert the float into an array of char (whatever the exact type format, just no some unmutable string)

Comment: @Gaddy "that means we can't access this source code at all ?" - that `InternalCall` means it is almost certainly written as C++ in the runtime host - still perfectly readable, and it will exist on github somewhere - here, in fact: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/933073140a0a7ca1f83084943e7516015f7e2ae8/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L2575

Comment: Surely this is what `StringBuilder` is for?

Comment: @MatthewWatson that depends entirely on why the OP needs a `char[]`

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, I was responding to his `want to append a lot lot of float (mixed with other types) in a very large string - and allocate this string only one time at the end`. You can use `StringBuilder` to do that (via [`AppendFormat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b(v=vs.110).aspx). At least then the buffer is only allocated twice (if you set the capacity appropriately) - once to allocate an array to use with `StringBuilder.CopyTo()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: about the stringbuilder I answered on the dedicated answer - thanks !

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks a lot for the link to the C++ code, i'll study it

Comment: It must be possible to invoke `sprintf()` of the C runtime from C# with a pointer to the raw data of a C# char array (but I have no idea how to actually do that, so this is only a comment).

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution I finally wrote, thanks to the float.ToString() source code provided by Marc Gravell.

It's much simplified but it seems to work pretty well for now (maybe I missed some special cases).
The only major difference I see is that very small float like  5.34E-05 will be written basically like 0.0000534 (and actually I prefer like that)

For info here is my full StringFast class (Unity C# code): http://pastebin.com/HqAw2pTG. And some tests using it here: http://pastebin.com/brynBFyC

The test runs 1000 times these operations: 4 appends (2 string, a float and an int) and 1 string replacement. I run the tests using string with + and Concat(), using StringBuilder, and using my StringFast class. Of course for the last two I do not recreate them every time.

Here are the results, with the memory allocation and the time:

- string (+) : 302.7KB, 1.75ms
- string (.concat) : 302.7KB, 1.85ms
- StringBuilder : 259.8KB, 1.81ms
- StringFast: 58.6KB, 1.68ms

And if I replace my 5 operations by a concatenation of 100 floats :

- string (+) : 36.8MB, 116.19ms
- string (.concat) : 36.8MB, 116.19ms
- StringBuilder : 6.0MB, 63.26ms
- StringFast: 0.6MB, 51.09ms

As you can see the StringBuilder is not that great, especially when there are only a couple of operations on the string.
The allocations of the StringFast class are only caused by the final ToString() I do (in order to be able to use the string with other functions)

Here is the code for the float conversion to a char array:

```
///<summary>Append a float without memory allocation.</summary>
public StringFast Append( float valueF )
{
    double value = valueF;
    m_isStringGenerated = false;
    ReallocateIFN( 32 ); // Check we have enough buffer allocated to handle any float number

    // Handle the 0 case
    if( value == 0 )
    {
        m_buffer[ m_bufferPos++ ] = '0';
        return this;
    }

    // Handle the negative case
    if( value < 0 )
    {
        value = -value;
        m_buffer[ m_bufferPos++ ] = '-';
    }

    // Get the 7 meaningful digits as a long
    int nbDecimals = 0;
    while( value < 1000000 )
    {
        value *= 10;
        nbDecimals++;
    }
    long valueLong = (long)System.Math.Round( value );

    // Parse the number in reverse order
    int nbChars = 0;
    bool isLeadingZero = true;
    while( valueLong != 0 || nbDecimals >= 0 )
    {
        // We stop removing leading 0 when non-0 or decimal digit
        if( valueLong%10 != 0 || nbDecimals <= 0 )
            isLeadingZero = false;

        // Write the last digit (unless a leading zero)
        if( !isLeadingZero )
            m_buffer[ m_bufferPos + (nbChars++) ] = (char)('0' + valueLong%10);

        // Add the decimal point
        if( --nbDecimals == 0 && !isLeadingZero )
            m_buffer[ m_bufferPos + (nbChars++) ] = '.';

        valueLong /= 10;
    }
    m_bufferPos += nbChars;

    // Reverse the result
    for( int i=nbChars/2-1; i>=0; i-- )
    {
        char c = m_buffer[ m_bufferPos-i-1 ];
        m_buffer[ m_bufferPos-i-1 ] = m_buffer[ m_bufferPos-nbChars+i ];
        m_buffer[ m_bufferPos-nbChars+i ] = c;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the C stdlib `sprintf()` and friends which should solve most of your formatting and data problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479210/3150802 for an example. Keeping track of the printing position, i.e. the index into the char array, by evaluating `sprintf()`'s return value will be important.

There is some performance penalty for crossing the managed/unmanaged boundary which is unavoidable. A possible mitigation strategy is to reduce the number of such crossings, for example by writing a C wrapper function which receives a large array of floats and writes them all in one go, using `s*printf()`.

The potential penalty for data marshaling (i.e. back-and-forth converting between CLI and native representations) may not be an issue for PODs like floats and addresses if they are bit-wise identical in both worlds.

Comment: Very good idea!  I'm not sure about the performances, won't it take some times to make the dll C calls from the C#  ? Definitely worth testing!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the overhead of doing this will dwarf the savings... Pinning the char array isn't cheap.

Comment: Worth testing though!

Comment: @MatthewWatson "Dwarf": Very possible. "Pinning": Is that the costly part, indeed? I thought that *keeping an object pinned for a long time* can be costly (but in terms of memory usage/fragmentation, not time). Whether some costly string conversion is performed when e.g. marshaling a string (buffer) is to be investigated. Also, [`Char` arrays need marshaling while `sbyte` arrays don't,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx) so it may be advisable to use raw byte arrays for the `sprintf` buffer.

Comment: I think char[] arrays are just passed as a pointer (after pinning) during the marshalling, so that shouldn't be too much overhead. But you might need to use `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes to ensure that it isn't copied.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems that you want to be able to format a lot of floats (and other value types) into a very large array of characters, without having to do a lot of memory allocations.

It's not possible to avoid all memory allocations, but you can mimimise them by using `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` and `StringBuilder.CopyTo()`.

If you have some idea of the maximum length of the final char array, you can initialise a `StringBuilder` with a capacity large enough to hold it. This potentially reduces the number of memory allocations, but at the expense of wasting memory if you make the buffer too large.

Code goes something like this:

```
int capacity = 8192; // If you have some idea of the final string length.
var sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);

for (float x = 0; x < 1000; x += 1.2345f)
    sb.AppendFormat(", {0}", x);

char[] array = new char[sb.Length];

sb.CopyTo(0, array, 0, sb.Length); // Now array[] contains the result.
```

Note that the minimum number of *buffer* allocations here is two: One for the internal buffer used by `StringBuilder` and one for the char[] array.

However, it is likely that a great many other small allocations will be taking place behind the scenes - but because of the way the GC works they are unlikely to make their way into any generation 1 collections, so it is not likely to cause a performance issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But stringbuilder actually makes a lot of memory allocation (at least in the c# version used by Unity Mono compiler). Of course much less than some string basic appends, but still too much when you really want to avoid memory allocations. 

And yes in some (unity) games that need a lot of performances, those allocations actually matters a lot (and you can easily see where they are with the profiler)

Comment: More precisely in your example : 

- 83.7kb allocated in the loop (with 811 iterations). 
- 52kb if I replace your .AppendFormat by just .Append(x)
- 0 if I replace it by Append("blabla").
- 6.2Mb if I use a string with str += ", " + x;

So StringBuilder is very good but far from perfect unfortunately

Comment: @Gaddy Well you're not going to get "perfect" (without writing your own floating point number formatter), but you just need "good enough"... Remember, GC is pretty cheap for objects that don't make it past generation 0.

Comment: Yep this is the idea, to redo the float formatter - it may not be that complicated. I checked the function given earlier (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/933073140a0a7ca1f83084943e7516015f7e2ae8/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L2575), there are some interesting explanation but i've yet to concentrate a little better to perfectly understand ^^

Comment: I finally managed to do this formatter, see my answer below (with also the results about the not-that-good StringBuilder)